# IRS federal refund paper check

Tags: united-states, check, europe

I worked in the US this summer and I received a paper check from tax returns on my address in the US. But I live in Europe now, and I don't have an American debit card.

Can a friend of mine who has the check cash it out for me on his bank account?
Or is there another way to get the money to me?

Comment: Related: [How do I cash a USD check in Europe, quickly?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/36615/10997)

Comment: Have you asked your bank if they will accept your check?

Comment: @YosefWeiner This is not yet a duplicate question, in my opinion, until the OP gives us more information about what his bank told him. Also, this question is about a treasury check, which is [often treated differently by banks](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/48399/10997) than private checks.

Comment: @BenMiller Actually, your answer to [Are there societal endorsement requirements for US Government checks....](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/48399/5760) is much more relevant to this case sine, as you pointed out there, US Federal Tax Refund checks follow different rules.